# How do I plot a function in 3D using mesgrid and mesh?

Tags: matlab, plot, surface

So I have a very lengthy function which maps out the height for a more advanced function with many peaks and valleys.

I am supposed to plot this surface constrained on the x and y axis, where x spans from 0 to 10 of 1000 evenly spaced poiints, likewise for y.

However I don't really understand the intricacies of meshgrid and mesh.

As mentioned before here is the intricate function which I am supposed to plot.

```
 function z = topography(x,y)


z= 0.001*(x-3).^2   +0.001*(y-4).^2 ...   
+0.5*exp(-0.25.*(x-11).^2-0.01*y.^2)...     
+0.5*exp(-0.01.*x.^2-0.25*(y-11).^2)...     
+0.5*exp(-0.1.*(x+1).^2-0.01*(y-5).^2)...    
+0.3*exp(-0.1.*(x-3.5).^2-0.5*(y+1).^2)... 
+0.5*exp(-0.1.*(x-8).^2-0.1*(y-0).^2)...  
+1.*exp(-0.1.*(x-9).^2-0.1*(y-8.5).^2)...  
+0.5*exp(-0.5.*(x-6).^2-0.1*(y-6).^2)...   
+0.25*exp(-0.5.*(x-3).^2-0.5*(y-8).^2)...  
+0.5*exp(-(x-5).^2-0.5*(y-5).^2)...    
+0.25*exp(-0.75.*(x-2).^2-(y-8).^2)...
+0.5*exp(-(x-6).^2-0.5*(y-3).^2)...
+0.5*exp(-(x-5).^2-0.5*(y-9).^2)...
+0.5*exp(-(x-9).^2-0.5*(y-5).^2);



end
```

Here is the method without using meshgrid:

```
xx=linspace(0,10,1000); % A vector with x-values from 0 to 10
yy=linspace(0,10,1000); % A vector with y-values from 0 to 10
zz=zeros(length(xx)); % A matrix of z-values
for i = 1 : length(xx)
   for j = 1 : length(yy)
         zz(i,j)= topography(xx(j),yy(i));
   end
end
figure(1);
mesh(xx, yy, zz) % The graph z=f(x,y) for topography
```

And this is my attempt of converting it into a script using meshgrid instead

```
xx = linspace(0,10,1000);
yy=linspace(0,10,1000);

zz=topography(x,y);

[x,y,z]=meshgrid(xx,yy,zz);

mesh(z);
```

I expect a nice 3D graph depicting the lengthy function "topograph". Instead I get the error message:

```
Requested 1000x1000x10201 (76.0GB) array exceeds maximum array size 
preference. Creation of
arrays greater than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become 
unresponsive.
See array size limit or preference panel for more information.

Error in meshgrid (line 77)
        xx = repmat(xx, ny, 1, nz);

Error in figure11 (line 6)
[x,y,z]=meshgrid(xx,yy,zz);
```

It says the array exceeds the array limit. But why is this not the case for the working script where this is done using loops?

Answer (score 0):

[`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) is generally used to only generate the independent variables. Once the grid of independent variables is created, the dependent variables are computed using them.

So in your script, the *x*-*y* plane is created using `meshgrid`, and the topography (i.e., the height) is created by evaluating the function with the those grids:

```
x = linspace(0,10,1000);
y = linspace(0,10,1000);

[xx, yy] = meshgrid(x,y);
zz = topography(xx, yy);

mesh(xx, yy, zz);
```

This assumes that the function is fully vectorized, so it can receive to matrices and produce an equally-size matrix. And the posted topography function appears to be just that.